# Proving that these isomorphisms are the $only$ isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How would I prove that the only isomorphisms  $\theta :\mathbb{Z[i]} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z[i]}$ are the identity map and $\theta(a+bi) = a-bi$?

I have no idea how to start this, my first thought was to try contradiction, "say there's some other isomorphism $\phi$" but I don't know where to go from there. I'm not asking for a full solution or anything, but any hints or tips would be really appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Show that a ring automorphism would be determined by where it sends $i$. Where can it?

Comment: so is this similar to the case for groups? I know that automorphisms send generators to generators, but is $\mathbb{Z[i]}$ generated by i?

Comment: @user78655 Have you tried proving that $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(i)$? Come on, try. Suppose you have $\phi(i)$ on hand. Then what is $\phi(a+bi)$ for arbitrary $a,b\in\Bbb Z$? All you need to do is use the fact that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.